# Meaning of inscription in synagogue

Tags: synagogue, star-of-david

On the ceiling of the main synagogue of Florence, Italy, is a Star of David with a Hebrew inscription inside it (below).  It looks like mem kaf bet heh.  What does it mean and why is it there?
[image]

Comment: I assume מי כמכה באלים ה

Comment: Does the synagogue have a website? Did you try emailing them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good guess @Joel K and thanks for the suggestion, @Double AA.  Here is their answer.  There was a second inscription, which I didn't notice (ceiling too high!):

> Gentile Maurice,
> grazie mille per la Sua mail.
> In una iscrizione c'è scritto MI KAMOCHA BAELIM HASHEM, “chi è come Te tra gli dei o Signore”. Nell'altra c'è scritto MI KAMOCHA NEEDAR BAKODESH, “chi è come Te circondato di santità”.
> Un saluto
> Giacomo

> Sinagoga e Museo ebraico di Firenze
> Informazioni e prenotazioni
> Via Tevere, 14 - 50019 Osmannoro Sesto F.no (FI)
> T + 39 055290383
> [www.jewishflorence.it](http://www.jewishflorence.it)
> [www.operalaboratori.com](http://www.operalaboratori.com)

Translation:

> Dear Maurice, thank you very much for your email. In an inscription it
> is written MI KAMOCHA BAELIM HASHEM, "who is like You among the gods
> oh Lord". In the other it is written MI KAMOCHA NEEDAR BAKODESH, "who
> is like You surrounded by holiness". Greetings Giacomo

Comment: Did you correct them and tell them you're Jewish Maurice? ;-)

Comment: I don't get it.  They assumed I wasn't Jewish?

Comment: Yeah, they called you 'Gentile Maurice'  ;-)

Comment: AH!  "Gentile" means "kind" in Italian.  (As in gentle, gentleman, etc.)

Comment: I know, but it was funny to see that particular greeting on this website. Incidentally a friend of mine knows a lawyer in Spain named 'Gentile Goy'.

Comment: @יהושעק that's almost as good as the ger who went from being Oliver to Shalom - Oliver Shalom :-)